# Can't open terminal! Works only from folder

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Hello there. I am new in Ubuntu and I just installed python 3.6 and was happy about it but suddenly i noticed that I cant open terminal anymore. I used the shortcut before, but now it just doesn't work! I tried run Terminal from application but it just shows icon in task bar and then just goes away, nothing happens. But the weirdest thing is I can open it from folder and it is working just fine.

I thought it was caused by some my personal setting but in ~/.gconf I don't have any other folder so i can't delete some Terminal settings.

Hope someone knows what is going on.

Comment: Try with ALT + F2 and type **gnome-terminal** and see if it launches that way

Comment: And try not to go on deleting files because a program doesn't work, what you can do is reinstall the program by entering the tty. CTRL + ALT + F1 takes you to it and you type your user login and password, then you can use the terminal session to reinstall from there.

Comment: I tried everything actually. ALT+F2 gnome-terminal didn't work. I also removed terminal and installed it again but still can't start it by normal way. For now I'm using it by opening from home folder and it works well, but i guess this problem is temporary and i will find cure soon.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem. I solved it by

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

and change `#!/usr/bin/python3` to `#!/usr/bin/python3.6`.
I changed to 3.7 at first as I installed it, but it didn't work. It only works after I changed to 3.6.
Refer to [this](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-ubuntu-cannot-open-terminal/)

Answer (score 0):

You might have a compatible issue for the gnome-terminal Python script in your Ubuntu versus the newly installed python 3.6. Please refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/996318/ubuntu-16-04-cant-open-the-terminal-after-trying-to-install-python/1112721#1112721).