# Ubuntu 16.04: can't open the terminal after trying to install Python

Tags: 16.04, python, gnome-terminal

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu, but now I cannot open Terminal... I click on the Terminal icon and it doesn't start, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> isn't working either.

I've read different ways to fix this (and none of them worked)
One way was to open XTerm and type `gnome-terminal`. When I did that I got this output:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries < prefix >
Could not find platform dependent libraries < exec_prefix >
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to < prefix >[:< exec_prefix >]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
Current thread 0x00007f54f2451700 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Today I tried to install Python and it didn't work for some reason... maybe that caused some problem?

Another way that I read was to change the language and locale (I'm from Argentina)... but I have just found that **Language Support** doesn't open either!!

Comment: When you "tried to install Python", what exactly did you do? Ubuntu has Python installed by default, and many applications, including, iirc, GNOME terminal, depend on it

Comment: I downloaded and installed Anaconda following the instructions, so then I would have Jupyter Notebook. Everything was great during the installation, but when I typed "pip3 install --upgrade pip" failed because of some files of a folder "python3.5"
Then, I typed "pip3 install jupyter" and failed too with the same folder. Then I stopped trying

Comment: Perhaps try to re-install `gnome-terminal` from the Software Center? Either that, of do a CTRL+ALT+F1 and then `sudo apt install gnome-terminal` (or try `sudo apt install -f gnome-terminal` if that doesn't work).

Comment: When I try both this is the output: "E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?"

Comment: @CarolinaIacovone Please [edit] your question to add details.

Comment: Refer to [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/15433/301745), then report back here once you have that fixed.

Comment: @WJAndrea I read that and I've just tried those solutions and any of them worked. Then I run "sudo fuser -cuk /var/lib/dpkg/lock; sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock" and now my computer IS LITERALLY CRAZY. It restart itself all the time! Doesn't even "live" for a minute. I don't know what the hell just happened!!! And now I'm from my cellphone, I can't edit comments and it's pretty hard from here to find a solution

Comment: @CarolinaIacovone You'll probably need to reinstall Ubuntu then.

Comment: For the sake of clarity/posterity, forcibly removing `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` is the absolute last thing you should do. (There are many warnings in the linked thread about that.) It has a high chance of breaking your system and it appears that's exactly what's happened in this case. I'm not sure if this is a direct result of the original issue or just tangential.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same terminal problem after upgrading Python from 3.5 to 3.7. As noted, Python 3.5(m) comes preloaded in Ubuntu 16.04 and the executable is in /usr/bin whereas Python 3.7 is installed in /usr/local/lib. My XTerm showed:

```
dell:/usr/bin$ gnome-terminal 
bash: /usr/bin/gnome-terminal: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Once I changed the first line of "gnome-terminal" from #!/usr/bin/python3 to #!/usr/bin/python3.5m, it was working. On the other hand, if I changed it to #!/usr/local/bin/python3.7, it encountered the following error:

```
dell:/usr/bin$ gnome-terminal
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", line 9, in <module>
from gi.repository import GLib, Gio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

This shows that ubuntu 16.04 gnomi-terminal is supported by Python 3.5, but not 3.7.

In your case, your error was "ImportError: No module named 'encodings'". I suppose your Python is [3.5 or earlier](https://airbrake.io/blog/python-exception-handling/importerror-and-modulenotfounderror). I searched the Ubuntu16.04 gnome-terminal script, there is no such statement as "import encodings". As suggested, you might want to reinstall gnome-terminal. I am not familiar with Anaconda, but looks like the default installation of Anaconda2 includes Python 2.7 and Anaconda3 includes Python 3.7. For Python 3.5, you need to follow [this instruction](http://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/#how-do-i-get-the-latest-anaconda-with-python-3-5). So make sure your gnome-terminal Python script is supported by the installed Python version, to be sure, issue shell command "/usr/bin/python3 --version" or python3 -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"

Answer (score 0):

For me it was due to a mishandled manual Python upgrade, hence lots of dependencies were either missing or causing problems. The way I solved it was to run `sudo apt-get install libsuitesparse-dev` and then install the dependencies which were *PyGObject* and *PyCairo*. Doing this worked and my gnome-terminal is fired up when its icon is clicked.