# Terminal and Software update crash on open, python installation related

Tags: python, gnome-terminal

I installed Python3 yesterday, but I have the feeling I didn't do a good job:

```
:~$ gnome-terminal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", line 9, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GLib, Gio
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from 'gi' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

I get the same error when trying to remove the PPA (in 404) with:

```
 add-apt-repository --remove ppa:/jonathonf/python-3.7
```

And yet, Python runs smoothly.  This might be helpful too:

```
~$ python --version
Python 2.7.15rc1
~$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.0b3
~$ type -a python3; file $(type -aP python3)
python3 is /usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3: symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/python3
~$ python3.5 --version # Expected, I installed 3.6 and 3.7 - I only added the 3.5 link as a following desperate attempt
bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
~$ python3.6 --version
Python 3.6.5
~$ python3.7 --version
Python 3.7.0b3
```

Running Ubuntu 18.04

The error persists after re-installing `gnome-terminal`.  I've found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/996318/ubuntu-16-04-cant-open-the-terminal-after-trying-to-install-python) that doesn't have an answer, but they suggest to re-install Ubuntu, like, I hope they're joking (:

Comment: How did you install Python 3.7? What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I'm the one that commented about reinstalling Ubuntu on the linked post. That was because OP corrupted their packaging system (not sure which part). I'm not sure if that's a direct result of the original issue or tangential. I've added a comment to that effect on that post.

Comment: Update: regardless of how you installed Python 3.7, you've done it wrong. The program called `python3` must point to the version of Python 3 that came with Ubuntu (and that is Python 3.6 or lower for any current Ubuntu release). Run `type -a python3; file $(type -aP python3)` and that will give us more info about your current setup.

Comment: Thank you all for caring, question updated.  I used a few resources to Install Python, mainly ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/07/install-python-3-6-1-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts , at some point, I had to deviate with `ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{35m,34m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so; ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{36m,37m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 contains (and probably even installs by default) python 3.6 packages. Yet, for 18.04, you followed an article dated 2017/07 about how to install it for Ubuntu 16.04, an article that clearly predates your distro release. I know that my comment here is not helpful, sorry for that, but I sincerely hope that this experience here will help you in the future to take precaution which articles to blindly follow, and to look for more mainstream, more official approaches first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 3 in the [instructions you followed](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/07/install-python-3-6-1-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/) is wrong. Different versions of Python 3 are not alternatives. Thankfully, it should be easy to fix. Just use similar commands to the ones in the update at the bottom of the post:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python3
sudo ln -s python3.6 /usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  The weird thing (for me) is that I really taught I did that step too.  In fact, I could already type `python3.6` and I got: `Python 3.6.5`.  Is that possible or am I just missing too much sleep?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. Python 3.6.5 is the version that's installed by default on 18.04, so of course `python3.6` runs it. **`python3`** needs to run Python 3.6.5. Glad I could help, btw!