# Gnome-terminal doesn't open after repartition

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal

I repartitioned my Latitude e6430s laptop after removing Windows 10 and now gnome-terminal does not open. Nothing happens when I press the terminal icon from the icon tray or with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> when gnome-terminal is set as default using

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
There are 5 choices for the alternative x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator).

  Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/koi8rxterm               20        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/lxterm                   30        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/uxterm                   20        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/xterm                    20        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 0
```

Xterm and Visual Studio terminal work.

I can open gnome-terminal from the file explorer by right clicking and opening folders in the terminal.

Reinstalled python3 and GNOME terminal.

Another thread said to use this to diagnose:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-terminal
Reading package lists... Done
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
```

After uncommenting the dev-src lines in my sources.list file I get this message, but the GNOME terminal still doesn't open.

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-terminal
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Here are the logs:

```
$ gnome-terminal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", line 9, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GLib, Gio
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from 'gi' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal", line 9, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GLib, Gio
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from 'gi' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Sep 19 19:08 /usr/bin/python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
```

Comment: I think in the midst of trying to fix the problem I installed python3

Comment: I added that to my post. what does that do?

Comment: You broke your system by messing around with python. See this question and its answer for a possible out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105687/18-04-gnometerminal-wont-start or the suggested duplicate question